# Saving-loading hybrid (LLM-custom logic) workflows as a model in Langchain

Tags: serialization, model, langchain

I am using complex flows in an application for getting from users' input to producing a result.

The goal would be to treat the entire execution flow similarly how Tensorflow or ONNX, etc. treat flows: I should be able to save/load/serve experimental variants of the entire execution flows as models, rather than placing switches into the code or switching git branches, etc.

I see Langchain has nice implementation for serializing and loading (simple) chains, however it is very complex, could not figure out the best practice how to incorporate code parts that do not rely on LLMs at all. Even custom agents seem to be too tightly coupled with LLMs.

Is there a good sample to define loadable hybrid flows as a model and save them (LLM-related and non LLM steps) that are also non-sequential, but branch apart and execution paths merge later?

I tried the built in save and load mechanism for simple chains, I expect similar solution for arbitrary execution paths including purely custom code nodes.